# ImportError: No module named pytesseract in ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

i have installed two libraries `pillow` & `pytesseract`by `pip3`

in order to do ocr
when i run this code

```
import Image
from pytesseract import image_to_string

img = Image.open('mz.png')

print(image_to_string(img))
```

i am getting `ImportError: No module named pytesseract` error 
 when i again install  `pytesseract` it says `requirement satisfied`

whats wrong with this

Comment: can you please show the run command you are using ?

Comment: Have you installed the tesseract-ocr library?

Comment: Try: sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr

Comment: this code is there in a file ocr.py and i am running it by python3 ocr.py

Comment: i have installed  pytesseract by sudo pip3 install pytesseract

Comment: Could you share the complete error message you are getting?

Comment: Can you run `pip freeze` and check if `pytesseract` is listed in the dependencies

Answer (score 0):

You probably have mutliple Python versions installed and try to run your file with another one as the one you have installed the packages into

Comment: how is this an answer ? you could of write it as a comment and get more info from OP before posting that answer .

Comment: no its not a version issue i have installed it for python3  and for the same i am using it

Comment: @ddor254 because it likely is the answer since ubuntu comes with multiple versions and if he properly installed the package he should be able to import it.

Comment: the key point here is the word "likely" , if something is unclear we wait for additional info :)

Comment: @chenyu Well you can install multiple versions of python 3.

Comment: @SV-97 the tutorial i was following there it was used for python 2 , now when i used it in installing python 2.7 environment its working like charm

Comment: It's only kind of what I meant, also you shouldn't do any Python 2 stuff as of now as it'll be deprecated next year and won't work anymore. Try creating a new python 3 virtual environment (venv) and install the dependencies inside of that and try to run your script from within that venv

Answer (score 0):

try and install tesseract ocr with `sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr`

and then use `sudo pip3 install pytesseract`

these 2 lines should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run following 3 commands first in sequential manner

1. `sudo apt-get update`
2. `sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr`
3. `sudo apt-get install libtesseract-dev`

and then install pytesseract using

```
pip install pytesseract
```

This should fix your problem.